# How to select the first suggested element using protractor?

Tags: html, typescript, protractor, automated-tests

1.Here is HTML code >

```
<div *ngFor="let profile of matchingProfiles" (click)="selectAlias(profile)" class="profile">
<img [src]="profile.profilePhotoBase64" class="alias-search-profile-image"/><p id="alias-search-text" class="alias-search-profile-text">{{ profile.alias }}</p></div>
```

2.here is my code :

```
element(by.id('ugcshare-textbox')).sendKeys('@mshinagi');
      browser.explore();
      element(by.id('alias-search-text')).get(0).click();
        browser.sleep(2000);
     element(by.id('share-submit')).click();
```

3. Error : I am getting error as " TypeError: element(...).get is not a function "[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr64x.png)

I want to select the first suggestion which is displayed in the image.Even though i am trying from the index but i was unsuccessful.Could someone please help me.

Comment: by.id returns a single item since ids are supposed to be unique. use something that returns a list of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could retrieve the entire list of items with a css selector instead of an id one and then get the first one from the list.

```
element.all(by.css('alias-search-profile-text')).get(0).click();
```

Comment: there is also a by.repeater selector but this issue suggests it's not working (yet) https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3205

Comment: If this was the right solution for you please mark it as the correct answer so other people will know too.